# Looks like a small error "Expected expression" but unable to find the solution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opencv, objective-c++

i used the project, in the below link

http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

when i integrate that project in to my project or vice versa error comes up
Errors image is shown below

If i run the sample it works fine but when i want to use  "OpenCVClientViewController" then it shows an error

I integrated both UIImage+OpenCV.h and UIImage+OpenCV.mm also

[image]
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: My problem was that i used #import "UIImage+OpenCV.h" in another .h file. when i only include it in a .mm file it compiles file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your implementation file is `.m` (Objective-C), although it should be `.mm` (Objective-C++).

Comment: It's already in .mm   both OpenCVClientViewControllerrAppDelegate and OpenCVClientViewController  But when i import OpenCVClientViewController where it requires then i called one method "processFrame" in OpenCVClientViewController it shows the error  @Cfr

Comment: Post your class sources on somewhere.

Comment: yes u r correct i changed my file  to .mm where i used openCV .. Here  this problem is solved later i got Apple Mach-o Linker(id) Error ..still i am searching for this problem @Cfr

Comment: It seems you have not linked a the library or framework. Make sure `{OpenCV, CoreVideo, CoreMedia, AVFoundation, ImageIO}.framework` and `libz.dylib` are present in your project's `Framework` folder.

Comment: Those frameworks are included... Do we need to set any header search paths or other linker flags? @Cfr

Comment: You have to put those in "Link Binary with Libraries" in "Build Phases". Possibly you have to add path in "Framework Search Paths".

Comment: What is the necessary path to add in "Framework Search Paths"? @Cfr

Comment: the path were you framework is located (i.e. project path in case you have copied framework), see aptogo's project as a reference.

Comment: dunno, try to drop `arm7s` from `Valid Architectures`.